# Getting private key from ServiceResource create_key_pair

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I know how to obtain the private key of a AWS Key Pair in boto3:

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('ec2')
dict_key_pair = client.create_key_pair(KeyName="temp-1")
private_key = dict_key_pair['KeyMaterial']
```

But I'd prefer to get a `EC2.KeyPair` instance instead of a dict.

I understand that the way to create such an instance is:

```
service_resource = boto3.resource('ec2')
entity_key_pair = service_resource.create_key_pair(KeyName="temp-2")
```

Unfortunately I cannot find out how to extract the private key from the newly created object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like an issue in how the `EC2.KeyPair` shape is modeled, specifically for `create_key_pair`. I opened a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/228) to track progress on fixing the issue.